# Should this site have Community Promotion Ads?

Tags: discussion, advertising

I'm a fan of what's called "Community promotion ads" on SE sites. Such as the [currently active version of it on Drupal.SE](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3606/39516). Checkout this link if you're not familiar with such ads, to understand the rules of the game, and also see some real world samples.

If you do checkout the above link, and want to help "me" to promote DevOps.SE, then make sure to look at [this specific ad over there](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3644/39516) (disclosure: it's mine ...). Or if you rather want to try it out via this question (to see what will happen if it ever gets enough votes over there), just click on this image below:

[image: Facing DevOps challenges with Drupal? There is an SE-site for it!]

The kind of actual ads which, IMO, could make sense for DevOps are (among probably many other variations):

- DevOps related **events**, as a variation of "[What are the Devops-related conferences happening around the world?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/504/40)".
- DevOps related **training**, as a variation of "[Which university has a good postgraduate DevOps program?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/599/40)".
- DevOps related **open source software recommendations**.
- ... what else?

**My questions**:

- How about also having such ads on DevOps.SE, does that make sense (already)?
- If so, who or what is required to get it going on DevOps.SE? Is that something that one of the (new) mods can do, or is there some other magic behind the SE-scenes needed for that?

PS: the (red) [community-ads](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag is available already, but I don't have the required privilege for any red tags ...

Comment: Side note: red tags are reserved to mods and SE staff :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, Community Ads **on this site** aren't available until [graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260754/336144).

> In keeping with your feedback, we’re considering laying out the mechanics of graduation a little differently in the coming days. It would look like this:
>
> #### The Community Team announces that a site is cleared for graduation. Without delay...
>
> - the beta label is removed
> - elections are held
> - migration paths are set up
> - ***community ads are run***
> - a link to the site is added to the footer

(emphasis mine)

The site will graduate on receiving approximately 10 questions per day consistently. Until that point, there won't be any ads here, but you can always share relevant links in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54506/devops).

I haven't ever seen a beta site with Community Ads, and I don't believe it's usual practice to enable them—instead, let's focus on growing and graduating the site before worrying about the ads.

---

Promoting this site with Community Ads on *other* SE sites can work well though, just like what you've done with Drupal.SE. We did this on [IoT Stack Exchange](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172/lets-advertise-with-community-ads), and it does seem to attract a fair bit of traffic.

Comment: This answer is correct.  Community Ads are not enabled until the site graduates when it reaches about 10 questions/day.

Comment: Interesting answer (didn't know that restriction). Though marking it as "accepted", as I do now, is a bit strange in this case (don't be surprised if I ever un-accept ... after graduation!)